# Navigating through array and inserting into SQL - php (weird array structure)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a project half-way through and I got this weird array which I now need to go through and store in a database.

The `(weird) array $fields` is like this:

```
array(10) {
    ["item_id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["itemname"]=> array(3) {
        [1]=> string(18) "Keyboard in en" 
        [2]=> string(21) "Keyboard in gr" 
        [3]=> string(20) "Keyboard in ru" 
    } 
    ["shortDesc"]=> array(3) {
        [1]=> string(0) "short_d en" 
        [2]=> string(0) "short_d gr" 
        [3]=> string(0) "short_d ru" 
    }
    ["description"]=> array(3) {
        [1]=> string(7) "en test" 
        [2]=> string(7) "gr test" 
        [3]=> string(7) "ru test" 
    }
    ["item_code"]=> string(12) "PH31004PCS"
}
```

The `table structure` is like this:

```
id(AI) | language_id | item_code | item_name | short_description  | description |
```

I need to **automatically** find the number of languages, (in the example is 3 but there could be more), and insert for each row the appropriate data.

**Example:** The row for English and Russian would be like this:

```
| id(AI) | language_id | item_code  | item_name      | short_description  | description |
+--------+-------------+------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+
| 1      | 1           | PH31004PCS | Keyboard in en | short_d en         | en test     |
| 2      | 3           | PH31004PCS | Keyboard in ru | short_d ru         | ru test     |
```

**The problem:** How should I navigate the array so I can store each row correctly and for all languages.

---

*Failed attempts*

However I tried to navigate the `array` all I managed to do was to get each `inner array` individually, all the `names` then all the `short descriptions` and then all the `descriptions`, **instead** of the `first` **then** `second` for each `inner array` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use for in this case. But first you need to prepare the values.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

// prepare values
$num_rows = count($array['itemname']); // get the number of rows of array
$item_id = $array['item_id']; // get the item id
$item_code = $array['item_code']; // get itemcode
unset($array['item_id'], $array['item_code']); // unset them, you don't need them when you loop later

// as usual, prepare
$insert = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO table_name (language_id, item_code, item_name, short_description, description)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
');

// start zero or 1 of $i
for($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    // you need to figure out how to get the language id, might be another select here

    $insert->bind_param('issss', $language_id, $item_code, $array['itemname'][$i], $array['shortDesc'][$i], $array['description'][$i]);
    $insert->execute();
}
```

This is just the basic idea. Most likely you didn't post all of the contents since it looks like you have more data inside the array `array(10)`.

Comment: "`Most likely you didn't post all of the contents`" Yep just the important ones :D, Although its very similar to @Deer-Outdoor.nl's anwer, I chose yours as the correct because of the extra information with the database :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = count($array['item_id']);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $lang_id = $array['item_id'];
    $item_code = $array['item_code'];
    $item_name = $array['itemname'][$i];
    $short_desc = $array['shortDesc'][$i];
    $desc = $array['description'][$i];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `your_table_name_here` (`language_id`, `item_code`, `item_name`, `short_description`, `description`) VALUES ('$lang_id', '$item_code', '$item_name','$short_desc','$desc')";
    //dont forget to fire ur sql at the database!!
}
```

Something like this maybe?

Comment: Yep exactly like this :D, the reason I chose the other answer as the correct is only because of the extra info for the database.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Okay np. glad i could help.